# WebSocket Connection doesnt work with Android 13 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, dart, websocket

I am trying to make a project in Flutter. Everything works fine with Android 11 Emulator, but when I tried to debug it on real devices/emulators with Android 13 and 14 I do not receive any websocket message, also didnt get any exception or error.

Websocket Connection Implementation

```
final String url = "wss://******";
if (_webSocket == null) {
_webSocket = await WebSocket.connect(url);}
```

Do you have any thoughts?

Tryed to edit my manifest, but didnt help.
debug manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".YourActivityName" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You better remive the usesClearTextTeaffic from th activity.

Comment: @blackapps Why? I thought it can be the solution for my problem isnt it?

Comment: It is nonsense to put it on an activity.